# How do I get online predictions in javascript for my model on Cloud Machine Learning Engine?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-ml-engine

I have successfully deployed on model on Cloud ML Engine and verified it is working with `gcloud ml-engine models predict` by following [the instructions](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/how-tos/online-predict), now I want to send predictions to it from my web app / javascript code. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The online prediction API is a REST API, so you can use any library for sending HTTPS requests, although you will need to use [Google's OAuth](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client) library to get your credentials. We will use the [`googleapis`](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/apis/oauth2/v2) library for simplicity.

The format of the prediction request is JSON, as described in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/reference/rest/v1/projects/predict).

To exemplify, consider the [Census](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/tree/master/census) example. A client for that might look like:

```
var google = require('googleapis');

var ml = google.ml('v1');

function auth(callback) {
    google.auth.getApplicationDefault(function(err, authClient) {
        if (err) {
            return callback(err);
        }

        if (authClient.createScopedRequired && authClient.createScopedRequired()) {
            authClient = authClient.createScoped([
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'
            ]);
        }
        callback(null, authClient);
    });
}

var instance = {
    age: 25,
    workclass: " Private",
    education: " 11th",
    education_num: 7,
    marital_status: " Never - married",
    occupation: " Machine - op - inspct",
    relationship: " Own - child",
    race: " Black",
    gender: " Male",
    capital_gain: 0,
    capital_loss: 0,
    hours_per_week: 40,
    native_country: " United - Stats"
}

auth(function(err, authClient) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
    } else {
        var ml = google.ml({
            version: 'v1',
            auth: authClient
        });

        // Predict
        ml.projects.predict({
            name: 'projects/MY_PROJECT/models/census',
            resource: {
                instances: [instance]
            }
        }, function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                return callback(err);
            }

            console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
        });
    }
});
```